# spring jmx authentication

Tags: java, spring, jmx

How can i turn on authentication using jmx on spring web app ?

Comment: That's far too vague. You'll need to do better than that if you don't want to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look here for a solution that is almost working for me:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=73677

The only unresolved issue is how to make JMX client use the same connection to server when authenticating and when doing the secure operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
<bean id="serverConnector" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.ConnectorServerFactoryBean">
    <property name="objectName" value="connector:name=rmi" />
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://:9875/jmxrmi" />
    <property name="environment">
        <map>
            <entry key="jmx.remote.x.password.file" value="C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\lib\management\jmxremote.password" />
            <entry key="jmx.remote.x.access.file" value="C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\lib\management\jmxremote.access" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Could you provide some explanations to your answer?

Answer (score 0):

SpringConfig

```
<bean id="annotationTestMBean" class="com.greenline.appservice.web.bean.AnnotationTestMBean"/>

<!-- Spring JMX 配置  begin --> 
<bean id="registry" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiRegistryFactoryBean">
    <property name="port" value="9875" />
    <property name="alwaysCreate" value="true" />
</bean>
<bean id="serverConnector" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.ConnectorServerFactoryBean">
    <property name="objectName" value="connector:name=rmi" />
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://192.168.214.63:9875/myconnector" />
    <!--jmxmp协议
    <property name="objectName" value="connector:name=jmxmp" />
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="service:jmx:jmxmp://192.168.214.63:9875" />
    -->
    <property name="environment">
        <!-- the following is only valid when the sun jmx implementation is used -->
        <map>
            <entry key="jmx.remote.x.password.file" value="C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\lib\management\jmxremote.password" />
            <entry key="jmx.remote.x.access.file" value="C:\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre\lib\management\jmxremote.access" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
<context:mbean-export registration="replaceExisting"/>  
<!-- Spring JMX 配置  end-->
```

you can see access&password file
JDK_Path\jre\lib\management\jmxremote.password
JDK_Path\jre\lib\management\jmxremote.access

JMX and Spring Part1-3
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/07/jmx-and-spring-part-1.html

oracle-Remote Management Applications (jmx)
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19698-01/816-7609/6mdjrf861/index.html